# lifecycle callbacks on instance and class methods in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
module Gym
  def self.included(class_or_module)
    class_or_module.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    class_or_module.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def build
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def open
    end

    def book_for_practice
    end

    def close
    end
  end
end
```

this is an example in the Ruby's Object Lifecycle Callbacks section of RubyMonk. I don't understand how it's supposed to work or what the point of this is. `self.included` should just document how the two modules within `Gym` get used, right? why does `class_or_module` then get sent/extended? why doesn't it get saved in some sort of arrays that document the lifecyle, like in the examples leading up to this one, such as

```
  @@extended_objects = []

  def self.extended_objects
    @@extended_objects
  end

  def self.extended(class_or_module)
    @@extended_objects << class_or_module
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not just documentation. `self.included` is a callback method that gets called as soon as the module is being included in any other module or class.

Instance methods are included via `send`, class or module methods via `extend` in that example.

Find out more in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-included).

Comment: and what effect does `self.included` produce here? it doesn't print anything to the console and the module or class will be included whether I define `self.included` or not?

Comment: It doesn't do anything unless you are including the module into any other class. Then it gets called by the interpreter. Normally this happenings when the app is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your Question One by one.

**1: `self.included should just document how the two modules within Gym get used ?`**

```
module A
  def instance_methods_1
    p 'hello instance_methods_1'
  end
  def instance_methods_2
    p 'hello instance_methods_2'
  end

  module KlassMethods
    def klass_methods_1
      p 'Hello!! klass_methods_1'
    end
    def klass_methods_2
      p 'Hello!! klass_methods_2'
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A  # instead of writing two piece of code like this we could wrap in one using `self.included` method Hook
  extend A::KlassMethods
end

B.new.instance_methods_1
B.new.instance_methods_2
B.klass_methods_1
B.klass_methods_2
```

### Another version of same program with method hook using `self.included`

```
module A
  # this is special method one of the methods hook in ruby.
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(KlassMethods)
  end
  def instance_methods_1
    p 'hello instance_methods_1'
  end
  def instance_methods_2
    p 'hello instance_methods_2'
  end

  module KlassMethods
    def klass_methods_1
      p 'Hello!! klass_methods_1'
    end
    def klass_methods_2
      p 'Hello!! klass_methods_2'
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

B.new.instance_methods_1
B.new.instance_methods_2
B.klass_methods_1
B.klass_methods_2
```

**2:** **`self.included`**

1. To know more about  [included hook](http://www.sitepoint.com/hitchhikers-guide-to-metaprogramming-classmodule-hooks/) and
2. [Ruby Hook](http://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-important-hook-methods/)

**`3: why does class_or_module then get sent/extended ?`**

```
module AddAdditionalProperty
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def add_additional_property
      p 'ClassMethods::add_additional_property'
    end
  end

end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def test
      p 'Base test Method'
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, AddAdditionalProperty)
ActiveRecord::Base.add_additional_property

## Another version of same Program

module AddAdditionalProperty
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def add_additional_property
      p 'ClassMethods::add_additional_property'
    end
  end

end

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include AddAdditionalProperty
    def test
      p 'Base test Method'
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.add_additional_property
```

Hope this answer help you !!!

Comment: @sivanes Let us know whether our answer work to got  your point or still you have some issue